# Shortcut key have problems

Tags: livecode

I have got some of coding for Shortcut. but my problem is I have Scrolling filed when performing the shortcut key event then its also place particular key to the Scrolling field eg: if I press alt+b then the b placed inside scrolling field

```
on rawKeyDown theKeyNumber
     switch (theKeyNumber) 
      case 98 -- b
         if the altKey  is down then
           answer"Hai"
           end if
         break

   end switch
   pass rawKeyDown
end rawKeyDown
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is occurring because you're not exiting the rawKeyDown handler when the altKey is detected.  Try this:

```
on rawKeyDown theKeyNumber
   switch (theKeyNumber) 
      case 98 -- b
         if the altKey  is down then
            answer "Hai"
            exit rawKeyDown #<---EXIT HERE
         end if
      break

   end switch
   pass rawKeyDown
end rawKeyDown
```